# Why doesn't itertools.combination_with_replacement give 27 results for length-3 combinations of 3 values?

Tags: python, replace, combinations

Below is my code

```
import itertools
a = [1,2,3]
for i in itertools.combination_with_replacement(a,3):
    print i
```

Output

```
(1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3),(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3),(1, 3, 3)
(2, 2, 2),(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 3),(3, 3, 3)
```

Only 10 result is print out, but by formula, it should be 3^3 = 27 output.

So may i know, how to get the other output?
Sincerely thank for your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want cartesian product, not combinations.

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.product([1, 2, 3], repeat=3))
```